# Permutation test for correlated or non-independent data

Tags: correlation, repeated-measures, references, independence, permutation-test

I want to compare two correlation coefficients sharing a common variable in repeated measures setting. Suppose $r_{XY}$ is the correlation between $X$ and $Y$ and $r_{XZ}$ is the correlation between $X$ and $Z$.

How do I test the null hypothesis that $\mathbb{E}[r_{XY}] = \mathbb{E}[r_{XZ}]$ (equivalently $\mathbb{E}[r_{XY}] - \mathbb{E}[r_{XZ}] = 0$), using permutation test?

Because of the common variable $X$, I understand that Steiger z test is the way to go if I use parametric testing.

But if I want to do permutation test, would that involve any modifications to normal way of permuting labels and estimating the distribution of statistic under null hypothesis?

As a follow up, what I really want to compare are $r_{XY}^2$ and $r_{XZ}^2$. Would squaring bring additional changes?

Comment: The permutation test requires that the order of the observations can be exchanged.  This does not require independence.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Michael. I am writing a paper. can you suggest a reference for this?

Comment: When writing papers, please keep in mind that the pronoun "I" is _always_ capitalized -- any other spelling is incorrect. Whether justified or not, the writing of those who do not capitalize "I" is often taken less seriously.

Comment: You can look at Philip Good's book about permutation tests. Also there is the book by Westfall and Young on the use of permutation methods for p-value adjustment when applying multiple testing.  Since you are doing this as part of a research article, on this site you need to include the self-study tag.